# Intermittent mongodb socket timeout error

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I keep getting below error intermittently

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadTimeoutException: Timeout while receiving message
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateReadException(InternalStreamConnection.java:699) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar!/:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessageWithAdditionalTimeout(InternalStreamConnection.java:577) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar!/:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:413) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar!/:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receive(InternalStreamConnection.java:361) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar!/:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:229) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar!/:na]
at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:158) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.8.2.jar!/:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

I see there is no default value for readtimeout for the java mongodb driver.